# Symfony open a default page for restricted access

Tags: symfony, authentication, symfony-2.6

How can I redirect automaticaly an user when it enters a restricted page to /register-as-guest?

My wrong solution: in `security.yml` I set

```
firewalls:
    default:
        form_login:
            login_path: /register-as-guest
```

This works, but when user enters wrong credentials at login it is redirected to `/register-as-guest` ( `login_path` ) but should be redirected to `/login`.

Comment: Put the roote id in the login_path option: 
firewalls:
    default:
        form_login:
            login_path: id of the login roote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track :)
Just a little more configuration is needed, as you can see in [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#redirecting-after-login)
If you want explicit behavior to happen on login success/failure, you should use these config settings under the firewall:

```
firewall:
    default:
        ...
        form_login:
           ...
           # login success redirecting options
           always_use_default_target_path: false
           default_target_path:            / # use this if you want a standard page to be shown on login success
           target_path_parameter:          _target_path
           use_referer:                    false # set this to true to redirect back to the previously attempted page

           # login failure redirecting options
           failure_path:    /foo 
           failure_forward: false # this is what you need
           failure_path_parameter: _failure_path
           failure_handler: some.service.id
           success_handler: some.service.id
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the **[FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle)**, everything you need is included there then you don't have to implement it on your own, also it is very well documented it is very is to integrate into a project